# Supabase reset password error: "Auth Session Missing"

Tags: next.js, supabase, next.js13, supabase-js

The following function fails with error "Auth Session Missing"

```
const { error } = await supabase.auth.updateUser({
   password: password,
});
```

After getting the reset password link on my mail i redirect the user to '/reset' link.
The link i get look like this

```
https://www.example.com/reset#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik5rK1VQTmlRYk9RZ2xXMUUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.AcLI2nO1BbCqCwAgrQ8flIjkvC2kRtKcujfXpqRFVG0&expires_in=3600&refresh_token=rUB74qIa-G3GNh6mpJxWdg&token_type=bearer&type=recovery
```

But on submitting the new password i get the error.

I'm using "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs" for creating client.

Comment: How are you instantiating the client? You will need to use the `clientComponentClient` for the session to be parsed from the URL: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs#client-components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that certain providers automatically pre-load the URLs in the email for faster page loading. However, since Supabase reset links are designed for one-time use, this preloading action causes the URLs to expire prematurely, resulting in errors when users attempt to reset their passwords.

Possible solution could be adding captcha verification or just a button that redirects to the url given by supabase

Answer (score 2):

Now Supabase has a new package in SSR that avoid this problem redirecting to an api route in next.js. You need to use the new SSR package [Package here](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/creating-a-client).

To avoid this problem I use this guide:
[SSR reset password](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-password-reset#server-side-rendering-ssr)

I hope it work for you!

Answer (score 0):

supabase store cookie in the browser when you call

```
const { error } = await supabase.auth.updateUser({
   password: password,
});
```

when you open reset password link from other device or browser then it throw this error because the cookie is missing.